# Get varnish error logs

Tags: web, reverse-proxy, varnish

I'm using varnish in my web infrastructure. My problem is that I'm loocking for a way to get varnish logs itself, actually error logs.
I mean error logs of varnish, not the one my web server as explained in this tuto https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/configure-varnish-logs-varnishnsca-logrotate-and-awstats.html

Thus, what I wouls like is to catch varnish error logs. Can someone help me to reach this goal?

Thanks

Comment: Typing varnishlog on the command line may give you the information you need, it will show you the events as they occur.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/varnishlog  If not, you'll need to update the configuration to log as you would like.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about varnishlog and focussed on varnishnsca. Thanks, I will look and a give a feeback

Comment: Yes I can have logs now. And the log file is a binary one, but I didn't found any documentation of the file structure. I can read the file with the `strings` command for example, but I would like to know if the structure of the log file is described somewhere so that I can retrieve information appropriately. Thanks